# Quicker Way To Write List of Items For Drop-Down Boxes

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I'm learning Java and working with Swing at the moment. When I create a drop-down box, I create an array containing what I want to appear as options. But say, for example, I want my drop-down box to list the years 1900-2013 is there a better and quicker way to list these numbers rather then type them all out in one massive array? 
Like could I just say I want the array to hold all values between 2 parameters?

Comment: How about having a `for` loop filling the array/list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create a drop-down box, I create an array containing what I
>   want to appear as options. But say, for example, I want my drop-down
>   box to list the years 1900-2013

- use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) instead of [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- otherwise you would need to implements some of `AutoCompete for JComboBox`, because range with 1k Items isn't user friendly at all, nor working, bothering with selections in  this Object
- put `Date` to `DefaultComboBoxModel` instead of `int` or `Integer` (representing years) in the case that you want to working with `Date instance` from users selection

Comment: Hmm interesting..I'll give this way a go too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  Counts backwards from this year to 1900.

```
List<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
int thisyear =2013; //you could parse this out of a new Date() object instead
for (int y = thisYear; y >= 1900; y--) {
    years.add(Integer.toString(y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should generate an ArrayList of the required years.

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1900; i < 2014; i++){
    myArray.add(Integer.toString(i));
}

for(String s : myArray){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I believe generating a list like this is known as creating it dynamically, or 'at run time'.

Comment: @ruffles probably not - if you ever want to do something with the selected year, you don't want to convert it back into an integer :-) Or in other words: add the item (typically an object having a particular type) and let the renderer handle the visuals like its string representation (vs. adding the string rep directly)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approaches, not just looping through years.
For example you can create a custom model for combobox:

```
ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel ()
{
    @Override
    public Object getElementAt ( int index )
    {
        return 1900 + index;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize ()
    {
        return 114;
    }
};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox ( model );
```

That should be more than enough to generate the desired list.

Of course you can also use a simple array as data:

```
Integer[] years = new Integer[ 114 ];
for ( int i = 0; i <= 113; i++ )
{
    years[ i ] = 1900 + i;
}
ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel ( years );    
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox ( model );
```

Each approach has its pros and cons.

Model "approach" will consume much less resources at start of your application (in case your list is really really big), though it will generate values each time combobox renderer calls for the value or you are trying to retrieve it (atleast in my simple implementation - you can add values caching, that will fix that issue).

Values "approach" takes less coding and more obvious in some simple cases.

Comment: better not confuse newbies: the first is a particularly bad extension of DefaultComboBoxModel - it's both mutable and modifiable, without overriding those methods its notification will confuse the listeners